# DevStack Installation Error: Directory 'opt/stack/nova' is not installable

Tags: python, pip, openstack, devstack

I'm trying to install Devstack on Ubuntu 14.04 all of which is running in a VirtualBox VM.  When I run ./stack.sh the script runs for a little while then I get this error in the terminal:

```
   DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  
   See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
   Directory '/opt/stack/nova' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
   Storing debug log for failure in /home/name/.pip/pip.log
```

The pip.log shows:

```
    /usr/local/bin/pip run on Thu Aug 14 16:53:09 2014
    DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.
    See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
    Directory '/opt/stack/nova' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
    Exception information:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 260, 
    in run

    InstallRequirement.from_editable(name, default_vcs=options.default_vcs))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 114, in from_editable
    name, url, extras_override = parse_editable(editable_req, default_vcs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1693, in 
    parse_editable
    raise InstallationError("Directory %r is not installable. File 'setup.py' not 
    found." % url_no_extras)
    InstallationError: Directory '/opt/stack/nova' is not installable. File 'setup.py' 
    not found.
```

I can provide more details if necessary, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the `PYTHONPATH`? May be a `/<directory>/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is missing in it. Note you may have add the ones which are supposed to only really exist after installation. I added some comment on this issue, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333640/pip-python-differences-between-install-option-prefix-and-root-and).

Answer (score 6):

Try the following commands. Theses should get you working

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/stack/nova

sudo apt-get purge python-paste

sudo apt-get install python-paste

sudo apt-get purge python-pastedeploy

sudo apt-get install python-pastedeploy
```

do an `unstack.sh` and `stack.sh` again