# Pip (python) differences between `--install-option='--prefix'` and `--root` and `--target`

Tags: python, pip

The [`pip` documentation](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) lacks too much wordings (to my eyes), about parameters to deal with source and destinations.

I've experienced strange things installing Sphinx with `pip3` and playing with the options available to seemingly allow me to install it precisely where I wanted (for some reasons, I want to have each thing in its own directory). I say “playing”, not that I did not read the doc nor tried `--help`, but because the `pip3 help install` did not help, and the [pip install](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html) official documentation page is too short on this and actually says not more than the `pip3 help install`.

Here are the experiments done and the observations.

### First case with `--root`

I [downloaded the current Sphinx repository tarball](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/install.html), unpacked it, get into the newly created directory and did:

```
pip3 install --root /home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx -e .
```

I though this would be the same as `--prefix`, as there was no `--prefix` option visibly available. To my surprise, it installed the commands in the `bin` directory of Python3 (which is also installed locally in its own directory) along to some things in its library directory, and strange, instead of a `/home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx` directory, I get a `/home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx/home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx/…`: it appended the specified path to itself.

How especially the last point does make sense? What's the purpose of `--root`?

### Second case with `--target`

Then I though if  it's not `--root`, that may be `--target`, so I did (after a clean up):

```
pip3 install --target /home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx -e .
```

It did not work, complaining about an unrecognized `--home` option.

What is this `--home` (which I did not specified) it complains about, and what exactly is `--target`?

### Third case with `--install-option='--prefix=…'`

After some web‑searching and a thread on StackOverflow, I tried this:

```
pip3 install --install-option='--prefix=/home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx' -e .
```

It just complained it could not install a `.pth` file and something is wrong with my `PYTHONPATH`, which was addressable restarting the same with the addition of a variable definition:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx/lib/python3.4/site-packages
pip3 install --install-option='--prefix=/home/<user-name>/apps/sphinx' -e .
```

I just had to the set `PYTHONPATH` even before the directory actually exists and anything was installed in it, but this one was OK (whether or not `pip` should update `PYTHONPATH` itself during the process and remind to set it up definitively, is a debatable question).

This option, which was the good one, was also the less clearly visible one.

### Another last related one:

What's the difference between `--editable` and `--src`?

### Update #1

I can't tell if it's Sphinx related, but I noticed two additional things.

Doing

```
pip3 install --install-option='--prefix=<install-dir>' -e <repository-dir>
```

where *repository-dir* is a local check out of Sphinx, Sphinx gets installed in *install-dir*, is listed by `pip3 list` but can't be uninstalled.

On the opposite, doing

```
pip3 install --install-option='--prefix=<install-dir>' Sphinx
```

that is, letting `pip3` retrieving an archive, Sphinx is not installed in *install-dir*, is installed in the python directory instead, is listed by `pip3 list` and can be uninstalled.

Depending on whether the source is a local repository or a remote archive, it won't be installed at the same location and will not be or will be uninstallable.

Dependencies were not affected, were handled the same way in both cases (installed where expected, listed, and uninstallable).

### Update #2

The behaviour with `--root` make me feel about a kind of fake‑root (like the one you get when building a Debian package or when cross‑compiling). If it's intended to be the same, then the path which surprised me, is on the contrary, expected.

Comment: This should clearly summarize the question being asked. Instead, currently, the actual sentences with question marks are scattered around the whole body.

Answer (score 1):

First and obvious question: why don't you just install the package from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sphinx/1.2.2)?

```
sudo pip install sphinx
```

If you want to install anything that has a `setup.py` file with `pip` you can use the [`--editable`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-e) flag:

> `-e, --editable <path/url>`
>
> Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools “develop mode”) from a local project path or a VCS url.

So you can just issue the command (prefix with `sudo` if necessary):

```
pip3 install -e /path/to/pkg
```

where `/path/to/pkg` is the directory where `setup.py` can be found (where you extracted the files).

To answer the other questions:

1. [`--root <dir>`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption--root) is used to change the root directory of the file system where `pip` should install package resources, not to change where to find the package.
2. [`--target`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-t)  is used to tell `pip` in which folder to install the package.
3. [`--install-option`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption--install-option)  is used to set some variables that will be used by `setup.py`, not to change where `pip` should look for the file.

Comment: “why don't you just install the package from PyPI?” to see the last version or to install a modified version or to install my own.

Comment: “--install-option  is used to set some variables that will be used by setup.py, not to change where pip should look for the file”: and some `setup.py` may conform or not to these options? Are `--target` and `--install-option='--prefix'` to be used together?

Comment: IMO don't use `sudo` with pip, use the `--user` option or a virtualenv. Don't mix system python packages with personal ones. Otherwise install from Linux distribution's repo with either `apt` or `yum`