# Difference between pip install --target and --prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333640/pip-python-differences-between-install-option-prefix-and-root-and) was asked, but there was no accepted answer, it has been asked already 8 years ago and python is now 3.11 instead of 3.4.

From the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/):

```
--prefix <dir>
    Installation prefix where lib, bin and other top-level folders are placed
-t, --target <dir>
    Install packages into <dir>. By default this will not replace existing files/folders in <dir>.
    Use --upgrade to replace existing packages in <dir> with new versions.
```

**What I've tried?** When I used `pip install --target=$SOMEDIR`, I noticed that the `bin/` folder as well as all module folders are directly placed in `$SOMEDIR` whereas when using `--prefix` the module folders are places in `$SOMEDIR/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`. Why is that so?

**What am I expecting?** I want to install a packages from pypi and have it contained in `$SOMEDIR` without the installation interfering with the global python installation.

**My Question:** What is the difference between `pip install --prefix=$SOMEDIR`, `pip install --target=$SOMEDIR` and maybe even `PYTHONUSERBASE=$SOMEDIR pip install --user` and what are the respective use cases? They all seem to install a certain package and its dependencies in an alternative directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`--target ${SOMEDIR}/target`:

- ignores already installed dependencies and installs them
- `PYTHONPATH` needs to be set to `${SOMEDIR}/target`

`--prefix ${SOMEDIR}/prefix`:

- notices already installed dependencies
- `PYTHONPATH` needs to be set to `${SOMEDIR}/prefix/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`